# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirect without query string variables not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with one of my rewrite rules. I would like to redirect all of the following URL's to another URL without the query string.

```
/gallery/products.aspx?C=9&SC=&ID=428&P=10
/gallery/products.aspx?C=2&SC=2&ID=128&P=1
/gallery/products.aspx?ID=147&C=2&SC=&P=7
/gallery/products.aspx?ID=1337&C=15&SC=&P=1
/gallery/products.aspx?ID=1532&C=3&SC=&P=2
/gallery/products.aspx?C=9&SC=&ID=1489&P=1
/gallery/products.aspx?C=7&SC=&ID=100&P=2
/gallery/products.aspx?C=2
/gallery/products.aspx?ID=1328&C=14&SC=11&P=17
/gallery/products.aspx?C=1&SC=&ID=767&P=3
/gallery/products.aspx?ID=1270&C=1&SC=&P=26
```

and I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/products.aspx http://www.domain.com/category/? [L,R=301]
```

but it's not working. I checked it in a .htaccess simulator and it found the rule then redirected, but when I upload to my server, it doesn't redirect. I've also tried some other rules with no luck

Comment: aspx ?? htaccess ? shouldn't you be using web.config if you're hosted on IIS ?

Comment: These are old aspx pages from an old site/server. We need to redirect via .htaccess on current LAMP platform

Comment: What other rules do you have on your server's htaccess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make this work with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule products.aspx http://www.domain.com/category? [L,R=301]
```